# Any well written Facebook iOS SDK tutorial?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to integrate facebook graph into my app. I've tried to follow the official-creepy-nonexaustive documentation of facebook, but it doesn't work.

There are any well written tutorial out there?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [Facebook SDK – Posting to User News Feed](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/28/facebook-sdk-posting-to-user-news-feed/)

A recent, solid explanation of how to post to a user's feed, which should help get you there.

Comment: That has not worked well. Some kind of bug make the code doesn't work. I've not tryed to work with it too much, because I need to use directly the default sdk, to get the friends list. So, there are other good tutorials? Thanks